# input[type="email"]:valid and input[type="email"]:invalid aren't working

Tags: css, email, input, css-selectors, pseudo-class

When an email field in my form is selected, the label that describes the email field moves up and gets smaller:

[image]

My code looks like this:

```
input:focus + label,
input:valid + label /*Is supposed to leave the label over the text even if the input isn't valid*/ 
input:invalid + label{
    color: aqua;
    font-size: 100%;
    transform: translateY(-20px);
}
```

This works perfectly fine on input fields with type=text, but on email input fields, **the label moves down after the input field is deselected:**

[image: "]

Does anybody have an idea how I can fix this? I find it quite confusing that it happens if its type is "email", but not if it is "text"

```
<input type="text" for="Sname" name="Sname" id="Sname" maxlength="100" required>
<label for="Sname">Lorem</label><br>

<input type="text" id="Iname" name="Iname" maxlength="100" required>
<label for="Iname">ipsum</label>
                   
<label for="CB"> <input type="checkbox" id="CB" name="CB"> <span>Lorem dolor sit amet</span> </label>
                         
<input type="email" id="EmailInput" name="EmailInput" maxlength="150" disabled required>
<label for="EmailInput" id="EmailLabel">Mail</label>
```

Comment: Can you provide the html you working with as well?

Comment: Took a second because it distorted the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly why, but the solution was the following:

```
input[type="text"]:focus + label, 
input[type="text"]:valid + label,
input[type="email"]:focus + label, 
input[type="email"]:valid + label, 
input[type="email"]:invalid + label {
    color: aqua;
    font-size: 100%;
    transform: translateY(-20px);
}
```

I think input[type="text"] seemed to be confused if you would write     `input:invalid + label {...}`, probably because there is no invalid input in a text field.

Therefore, I specified the selection